# lodash check object properties has values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have object with several properties, says it's something like this

```
{ a: "", b: undefined }
```

in jsx is there any one line solution I can check whether that object's property is not empty or has value or not? If array there's a isEmpty method.

I tried this

```
const somethingKeyIsnotEmpty = Object.keys((props.something, key, val) => {
        return val[key] !== '' || val[key] !== undefined
})
```

Comment: you want to check whole object is empty or want to check specific property?

Comment: @MayankShukla every object

Comment: you want to check all the properties, and if any one of them is null or undefined then final output will be true otherwise false correct??

Comment: @MayankShukla yes

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In lodash, you can use _.some

```
_.some(props.something, _.isEmpty)
```

Comment: It's javascript. _.isEmpty is a function and functions are first class in javascript (you can pass it as an argument and return from other functions).

Comment: _.some is for collection not for object. Will it work?

Comment: An object is a collection of property/values. Anyways, _.some works on both arrays and objects. Please check the documentation - https://lodash.com/docs/#some

Comment: I think we shoule to check the path before check if it has value or not
`_.has(object, pathToProperty)`

Answer (score 32):

You can use lodash `_.every` and check if `_.values` are `_.isEmpty`

```
const profile = {
  name: 'John',
  age: ''
};

const emptyProfile = _.values(profile).every(_.isEmpty);

console.log(emptyProfile); // returns false
```

Comment: I have an array of objects and I want to check if age is empty or not how can I handle it?

Answer (score 6):

Possible ways:

Iterate all the keys and check the value:

```js
let obj = {a:0, b:2, c: undefined};

let isEmpty = false;

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if(obj[key] == undefined)
        isEmpty = true;
})

console.log('isEmpty: ', isEmpty);
```

Use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), like this:

```js
let obj = {a:0, b:1, c: undefined};

let isEmpty = Object.values(obj).some(el => el == undefined);

console.log('isEmpty: ', isEmpty);
```

Check the index of `undefined` and `null`:

```js
let obj = {a:1, b:2, c: undefined};

let isEmpty = Object.values(obj).indexOf(undefined) >= 0;

console.log('isEmpty: ', isEmpty);
```

Comment: why use some not every in your second block of code? I want to check whether is there any object are not defined or undefined.

Comment: @CeldricKang some will check if any of the the value is undefined then it will return true, we can use every also, and check if all the values are proper or not.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and elegant solution to check if all property values in an object is empty or not is following,

```
const ageList = {
  age1: 0,
  age: null
};

const allAgesEmpty = _.values(ageList).every((age) => !age);

console.log(allAgesEmpty); // returns true
```

Regarding the function inside _.every

- Note: Do not use _.empty inside every as empty of a number always return false.
  Read more here: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/496
- Note: if a property has a boolean value then you may need to modify the function even more

Answer (score 0):

const profile = {
name: 'John',
age: ''
};

const emptyProfile = *.values(profile).every(*.isEmpty);

This solution is more efficient to check if each key is really empty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).