# check for empty property value using lodash

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am trying to check the following for empty values using lodash:

```
data.payload{
      name: ""
}
```

My code:

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash.isempty';

if (isEmpty(data.payload)) {
```

The above is false, how can I validate for empty values?

I have this code in my helper:

```
export const isEmpty = some(obj, function(value) {
  return value === '';
}
```

);

In my action I have

```
    if (isEmpty(data.payload)) {
```

I get an error, **ReferenceError: obj is not defined** but I am passing the object...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962321/lodash-check-object-properties-has-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lodash check object properties has values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962321/lodash-check-object-properties-has-values)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `isEmpty()` to check for objects with nothing but *falsey* values, you can compose a function that uses `values()` and `compact()` to build an array of values from the object:

```js
const isEmptyObject = _.flow(_.values, _.compact, _.isEmpty);

isEmptyObject({});
// -> true

isEmptyObject({ name: '' });
// -> true

isEmptyObject({ name: 0 });
// -> true

isEmptyObject({ name: '...' });
// -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_.some(obj, function (value) { return value === "" })
```

You can use this, it will return true if there is any empty property and false if all are defined.

Comment: obj is your data.payload

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to react, I'm passing it as an argument? if (isEmpty(data.payload)) { still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

you can use `isEmpty()` from `lodash` like this

```
if(_.isEmpty(data.payload.name)){
}

or


import isEmpty from 'lodash.isempty';

if (isEmpty(data.payload.name)) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` or `every` from lodash to check generically all key has passed condition or some has passed condition.

```
["barney", 36, "test"].some(_.isEmpty); // false
["barney", 36, ""].some(_.isEmpty); // true
```

or

```
["barney", 36, "test"].every(_.isEmpty); // false
["", [], ""].every(_.isEmpty); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.isEmpty(_.omitBy(obj, _.isEmpty))
```

This will return true if all obj properties values are set to ""