# Handling when Obj does not have key

Tags: javascript

How can we make obj handle/execute a function when it does not have a key?

for example

```js
const abc = {
 a: () => console.log('key exist')
}


console.log(abc.a())

console.log (abc.c())
```

Here, `console.log(abc.a())` will print key exist but I want if someone who tries to access a key which does not exist then it should run a different a function.

I want it to handle this thing at object level i.e I can do `if (abc[c])` and then do something else but since I am going to call this obj from many different place and I don't want to have if-else condition.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use lodash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962321/lodash-check-object-properties-has-values/44962532   Or optional chaining depending on what version of JS you will support.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that in JavaScript. You need those if-else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```js
const abc = {
 a: () => console.log('key exist'),
 notfound: () => console.log('key does\'t exit')
}


console.log(abc.a())

console.log ((abc?.c||abc.notfound)())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the property c exists on the object first. i also added a check to see if it's indeed a function.

```js
const abc = {
  a: () => console.log('key exist')
}


console.log(abc.a());

console.log (abc.c && typeof abc.c === 'function' ? abc.c() : "not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Nullish coalescing operator to solve your issue:

> The **nullish coalescing operator (??)** is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.
>
> More info see [MDN Web Docs - Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).
>
> Nulish coalescing operator is part of the ECMAScript 2020 specification. Lookup [can i use](https://caniuse.com/?search=Nullish%20coalescing%20operator) for browser support details.

```js
//With external default
(() => {

  const abc = {
    a: () => console.log('key exist')
  }

  const myFunction = abc.c ?? (() => console.log("key doesn't exist"))
  myFunction();

})();

//With internal default
(() => {

  const abc = {
    a: () => console.log('key exist'),
    default: () => console.log("key doesn't exist")
  }

  const myFunction = abc.c ?? abc.default
  myFunction();

})();
```

If your project needs to support older browser, use **Binary logical operator OR (`||`)** instead:

> The **logical OR (||)** operator (logical disjunction) for a set of operands is true if and only if one or more of its operands is true.
>
> If a value can be converted to true, the value is so-called truthy. If a value can be converted to false, the value is so-called falsy.
>
> Expressions that can be converted to false
>
> - `null`
> - `NaN`
> - `0`
> - empty string (`""` or `''` or **``**)
> - `undefined`
>
> More info see [MDN Web Docs - Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

```js
//With external default
(() => {

  const abc = {
    a: () => console.log('key exist')
  }

  const myFunction = abc.c || (() => console.log("key doesn't exist"))
  myFunction();

})();

//With internal default
(() => {

  const abc = {
    a: () => console.log('key exist'),
    default: () => console.log("key doesn't exist")
  }

  const myFunction = abc.c || abc.default
  myFunction();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to avoid the use of `if/else` every time you need to run a function that may or may not exist, you can create a global function:

```js
const run = (cb) => typeof cb ===  "function" ? cb() : () => {}

const abc = {
  a: () => console.log('key exist')
}


console.log(run(abc.a))

console.log(run(abc.c))
```